# How to disable the loading message in the header of a jQuery Mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-loading-message

I want to disable the loading message in the **header only** when transitioning between jQuery Mobile pages.

Alternatively, if I can change the default "loading" text, that would also suffice.

I have tried

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

also `$.mobile.pageLoading( true );`

you can see an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/uRhGd/13/)

Answer (score 3):

See the docs for [mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/globalconfig.html) and use `loadingMessage` to set the default.

I believe you can programmatically change it with `$.mobile.loadingMessage` as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/uRhGd/16/ check that example. `$.mobile.loadingMessage = "";` still produces that small blip where there is a new message being displayed. I wish there was a way to slow down the page transition so you could see it clearer.

Comment: yes still stuc on this as well... been searching stackoverflow for a good answer. still searching lol

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting loadingMessage to false? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: how is this any different than the above answer?